# Getting the max or min date to be added to an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to get the max and min of salaries based on a month and get the timestamp on whichever the max or min falls
under.

I have an array that looks like this

```
    array:3 [
        0 => {
            "name": "Sarah"
            "jan": "1000"
            "feb": "123"
            "mar": "453"
            "apr": "677"
            "may": "98"
            "date": "2021-02-16 06:00:00"
        }
        1 => {
            "name": "Peter"
            "jan": "1234"
            "feb": "435"
            "mar": "18565"
            "apr": "3526"
            "may": "1345"
            "date": "2021-02-16 06:30:00"
        }
        2 => {#1411
            "name": "Chris"
            "jan": "125"
            "feb": "10643"
            "mar": "6547"
            "apr": "345"
            "may": "2356"
            "date": "2021-02-16 07:00:00"
        }
    ]
```

so I would like my array to look like this

```
    jan => [
        'max' => [
            'max' => 1234,
            'date' => 2021-02-16 06:30:00
        ],
        'min' => [
            'min' => 125,
            'date' => 2021-02-16 07:00:00
        ]
    ]
```

Here is my code

```
    $salaries = Salary::all();

    $jan = array_column($salaries->toArray(), 'jan');

    $jan_array['jan'] = [
        'max' => [
            'max' => max($jan),
            'date' => //max date should come here
        ],
        'min' => [
            'min' => min($jan),
            'date' => //min date should come here
        ],
    ]
```

Comment: What is your expected output when there is a tie for max, or min?  What if min and max are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @kien-nguyen answer, to utilize the excellent Laravel Collection more, it can be written like below.

```
$salaries = Salary::all();

$maxJan = $salaries->max('jan');
$minJan = $salaries->min('jan');

$jan_array['jan'] = [
    'max' => [
        'max' => $maxJan,
        'date' => $salaries->firstWhere('jan', $maxJan)->date,
    ],
    'min' => [
        'min' => $minJan,
        'date' => $salaries->firstWhere('jan', $minJan)->date,
    ],
];
```

Here you can directly call `max()` and `min()` on the Collection

```
$maxJan = $salaries->max('jan');
$minJan = $salaries->min('jan');
```

And also you can find the row with `maxJan` with `firstWhere()` and then access its `date` property.

```
        'date' => $salaries->firstWhere('jan', $maxJan)->date,
```

Comment: It looks better using your "Laravel-way"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_keys` to find index of max/min value in array and use it to get `date` value like this:

```php
$salaries = Salary::all();
$salaries_arr = $salaries->toArray();

$jan = array_column($salaries_arr, 'jan');
$jan_max = max($jan);
$jan_min = min($jan);

$jan_array['jan'] = [
  'max' => [
    'max' => $jan_max,
    'date' => $salaries_arr[array_keys($jan, $jan_max)[0]]['date']
  ],
  'min' => [
    'min' => $jan_min,
    'date' => $salaries_arr[array_keys($jan, $jan_min)[0]]['date']
  ],
];
```

If there are multiple max/min values, it will get the first one.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array", exception: "Error"` and the line it's talking about is `'date' => $salaries_arr[array_keys($jan, $jan_max)[0]]['date']`

Comment: Can you debug to check the type of `$salaries_arr`? I think it should be an array

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider that you have a following array **(Collection)**

```
$array = collect([
    [
        "name" =>  "Sarah",
        "jan" =>  "1000",
        "feb" =>  "123",
        "mar" =>  "453",
        "apr" =>  "677",
        "may" =>  "98",
        "date" =>  "2021-02-16 06:00:00",
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Peter",
        "jan" => "1234",
        "feb" => "435",
        "mar" => "18565",
        "apr" => "3526",
        "may" => "1345",
        "date" => "2021-02-16 06:30:00",
    ],
    [
        "name" =>  "Chris",
        "jan" =>  "125",
        "feb" =>  "10643",
        "mar" =>  "6547",
        "apr" =>  "345",
        "may" =>  "2356",
        "date" =>  "2021-02-16 07:00:00",
    ]
]);
```

We need min and max for all the months so decaling that as array

```
$months = [
  'jan', 
  'feb', 
  'mar', 
  'apr', 
  'may', 
  'jun', 
  'jul', 
  'aug', 
  'sep', 
  'oct', 
  'nov', 
  'dec'
];
```

Now Mapping the values to corresponding months

```
$monthsReport = [];

foreach($months as $month){

  $monthsReport[$month] = $array->map(function($value) use ($month){
                                $monthValue = Arr::get($value,$month,null);
                                $date = Arr::get($value,'date');

                                $returnArray['monthValue'] = $monthValue;
                                $returnArray['date'] = null;

                                if($monthValue){
                                  $returnArray['date'] = $date;
                                }

                                return $returnArray;
                          });
}
```

Now we need to calculate mix and mx of each month so

```
$collectionOfMonths = collect($monthsReport)
      ->map(function($value){
        $filterCheckFails = $value
                      ->map(function($value){
                          return array_filter($value);
                      })
                      ->filter()
                      ->isEmpty();

        if($filterCheckFails){
          return null;
         }
        return $value;
       })
      ->filter()
      ->map(function($value,$key){

        $minimimMonthValue = $value->min('monthValue');
        $minimimMonthDateArray = Arr::first($value,function($array) use ($minimimMonthValue){
          return Arr::get($array,'monthValue') == $minimimMonthValue;
        });
        $minimimMonthDate = Arr::get($minimimMonthDateArray,'date');

        $maximumMonthValue = $value->max('monthValue');
        $maximumMonthDateArray = Arr::first($value,function($array) use ($maximumMonthValue){
          return Arr::get($array,'monthValue') == $maximumMonthValue;
        });
        $maximumMonthDate = Arr::get($maximumMonthDateArray,'date');
        
        return [
          'min' => [
            'min' => $minimimMonthValue,
            'date' => $minimimMonthDate,
          ],
          'max' => [
            'max' => $maximumMonthValue,
            'date' => $maximumMonthDate,
          ],
        ];
      });
```

Live Demo [Here](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/69216cc7-ce97-417a-8782-47cf3a6fb8ac)

Comment: op also wants the date of min and max in each month too.